Given that $f(x) = f(\frac{x}{1-x}) \forall x \ne 1$, and $f$ is continuous at $0$. Find all such $f$.
Question
Given that $f(x) = f(\frac{x}{1-x}) \forall x \ne 1$, and $f$ is continuous at $0$. Find all such $f$.
Attempt
Substituting $x$ with $\frac{1}{n}$, I got that $f(\frac{1}{n}) = f(\frac{1}{n-1})$. But I am stuck here. I have tried few other substitutions for $x$ but they didn't help either. Kindly help.

Take $g(x)=f(\frac{1}{x})$. So $g(n)=g(n-1)$. So $g$ is a periodic function with period of $1$. So to make $f(x)$, take any function $g(x)$ with period of $1$, and then define $f(x)=g(1/x)$. [Need to check the constraint of $f$ being continuous at $0$ too]

I think the ‘continuous at $0$’ constraint together with the periodic nature will restrict $f$ to being just a constant function.

If you substitute $x \mapsto \frac{x}{1+x}$, for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $f\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right) = f(x)$. This would imply $f(1) = f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$.

@Sam yes I had gotten that, infact I got multiple other equalities as well $f(2) = f(-2)$, $f(3) = f(-1.5)$. But how to proceed from here?

@Debu see this graph for a function that satisfies your conditions except for being continuous at $0$.

Using induction in $n$, $$f(x) = f\left(\frac{x}{1-nx}\right) =  f\left(\frac{x}{1+nx}\right)\,\, \forall \,\, n \in \mathbb{N}. $$
The sequence $a_n(x) = \frac{x}{1+nx} \to 0$ as $n$ tends to infinity for every $x \ge 0$ and $b_n(x) = \frac{x}{1-nx} \to 0$ for every $x \le 0$. Thus taking the limit as $n\to \infty$ both sides and using continuity of $f(x)$ at $x=0$, $f(x) =f(0)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus $f$ is the constant function $f(0)$.
Edit: For $n=1$, it's given that $f(x) =   f\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)$. Substituting $x \mapsto \frac{x}{1+x}$ in the original functional equation, we have $f(x) =   f\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)$. The case for $n=1$ is clear. Now assume the given statement holds for some $n_o \in \mathbb{N}$, then $$f(x) = f\left(\frac{x}{1-n_0x}\right) =  f\left(\frac{x}{1+n_0x}\right). $$
and $$ f(x) = f\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right) =  f\left(\frac{\frac{x}{1-x}}{1-n_0\frac{x}{1-x}}\right) =  f\left(\frac{x}{1-(n_0+1)x}\right)\\ f(x) = f\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right) =  f\left(\frac{\frac{x}{1+x}}{1+n_0\frac{x}{1+x}}\right) =  f\left(\frac{x}{1+(n_0+1)x}\right). $$
Thus the statement follow from induction.

yes @lulu , any value taken by $f(0)$.

Rest of the argument I can follow. It's quite elegant. If you could just explain how did you get the first expression involving $n$.

Added the details in the solution @Debu

@Sam, congratulations ! Very good answer !
